# In Eclipse, how can I save layout settings for custom Perspectives into a file

Tags: eclipse-plugin

In Eclipse 4.x, I was trying to export layout settings for customized Perspectives into a file (programmatically). So I can import this file later into different Eclipse client on different workstation.

Here is what I did

```java
IPerspectiveRegistry perspectives = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getPerspectiveRegistry();
IPerspectiveDescriptor[] allPerspectives = perspectives.getPerspectives();

for (IPerspectiveDescriptor pDescriptor : allPerspectives) 
{
            // here I can get Label and Description from IPerspectiveDescriptor 
            // but how can I get the actual layout setting for the Perspective?

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: "I was trying to export layout settings" how did you try?

Comment: sorry, didn't make the story complete..

Comment: The details of the perspective are in the `MPerspective` object in the e4 application model. Since this is an EMF model you may be able to use EMF to save and load the information.

Comment: @greg-449, thank you for your hints. I am now able to retrieve a list of `MPerspective` from `EModelService` by using code..   `modelService.findElements(application, null, MPerspective.class, null);` However, it seems only return a list of perspectives that are currently opened (i.e. shows up on the top right corner beside the tool bar). Any ideas on how to get ALL perspectives (include closed ones)? Much appreciated..